# Syntax of mutate an d recode

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I'm struggling with getting the syntax correct for the code below. I'm trying to rename values from "i.x59.051" to "Acetone" in column named compound. Trying this code doesn't result in any changes in compound column.

Any suggestions?

```
 df%>%
  mutate(compound=recode(compound, "Acetone" = "i.x59.051", "Acetaldehyde"="i.x45.03"))
```

And here's the data:

```
df <- structure(list(days_incubated = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), compound = c("i.x59.051", "i.x45.03", "i.x59.051", 
"i.x45.03", "i.x59.051")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the order of the arguments.

```r
df %>%
   mutate(compound = recode(compound, "i.x59.051"="Acetone", "i.x45.03"="Acetaldehyde"))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#   days_incubated compound    
#            <int> <chr>       
# 1              0 Acetone     
# 2              0 Acetaldehyde
# 3              0 Acetone     
# 4              0 Acetaldehyde
# 5              0 Acetone
```

From `?recode`,

> ... the argument **names** should be the current values
> to be replaced, and the argument **values** should be the new
> (replacement) values.

(emphasis mine) From this, the *"current values"* includes `"i.x59.051"`, and its replacement value is `"Acetone"`.

Answer (score 0):

We can also pass an named vector

```
keyval <- setNames(c("Acetone", "Acetaldehyde"), c("i.x59.051", "i.x45.03"))
df %>%
     mutate(compound = recode(compound, !!! keyval))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#   days_incubated compound    
#           <int> <chr>       
#1              0 Acetone     
#2              0 Acetaldehyde
#3              0 Acetone     
#4              0 Acetaldehyde
#5              0 Acetone
```